# Angular HttpInterceptor swallowing the error

Tags: angular, error-handling, interceptor

I have an annoying issue with my Angular 11 app: when I execute the following code on my locale machine, everything is fine, the correct error message is displayed by my toastrService. But when this gets deployed to Azure, there I always get *Something went wrong! Please try again!* which is my error message for the case of an error different from HttpErrorResponse (check component code for displayed error message).

I have the following intercept method:

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    return next.handle(req).pipe(
        catchError(err => {
            // onError
            console.log(err);
            if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
                console.log(err.status);
                console.log(err.statusText);
                if (err.status === 401) {
                    this.LogoutFromApplication();
                }
            }
            return throwError(err);
        }));
}
```

and the following component logic:

```
this.httpService.post(url, body)
  .subscribe((result) => {
    ...
  },
  (errorResponse) => {
      this.operationFlag = false;
      console.log(JSON.stringify(errorResponse));
      if (errorResponse.error && errorResponse.error.ErrorMessage) {
        this.toastr.showError(errorResponse.error.ErrorMessage);
      } else {
        this.toastr.showError("Something went wrong! Please try again!");
      }
  });
```

Somehow the error is swallowed by the interceptor. The console.log-s inside the interceptor show that the error is there and it is an HttpErrorResponse but in the component an empty object is logged and the errorResponse object seems to be undefined.

Could you help me figure out what is the problem?

Comment: What does the console output of logging just errorResponse give, undefined?

Comment: It throws an error.
In the meantime I have a suspect of the root cause. We are using the Adal5HTTPService of adal-angular5 and I think that may be responsible of swallowing the error. I will update the topic if I have it confirmed.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it turned out that indeed the Adal5HttpService was responsible. It seems to incorrectly throw the error probably during the years that has passed since this part has been changed in rxjs. So the code above in the question is functioning properly, the message of this issue and investigation is that

*Do not narrow your search to the most obvious place of the issue, try to see the whole picture.*

Hope this helps to someone.